# python array.tostring() has NUL bytes in it

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, python-3.x

I have the following code (as an example) in a unittest TestCase

```
def test(self):
    a = array('u','\0'*3)
    a[0] = 'h'
    a[1] = 'h'
    a[2] = 'h'

    self.assertEqual(a.tostring(), "hhh")
```

The assertion fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: b'h\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00' != 'hhh'
```

Now I understand that the array I created is for Unicode characters which are 4 bytes long hence the extra 3 NUL bytes for every character I entered. My questions are:

1. Can I convert the string "hhh" into Unicode representation inline of my assert?
2. Is there a ascii option to create my array with?

EDIT: to answer the questions that have come up:
1. I am using Python 3
2. array comes from module array, can be imported with: from array import array

Comment: What is array? (where is it imported from? or what is the definition?)

Comment: I ask because it doesn't even run... >>> array.array('u','\0'*3) returns a Traceback.

Comment: Hi sorry you need to have the line from array import array

Comment: Strange, still doesn't run for me as written above.  ValueError: string length not a multiple of item size.  On 2.7.2 here.

Comment: Ah, works in Python3 that is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are working with Python3, which seems to lack a `'c'` option for `array`.

In this case, I would do

```
a = array.array("b",4*(0,))
a[0] = 'h'
a[1] = 'h'
a[2] = 'h'
```

Another option would be

```
a=array.array('u', "hhh") # the same as yours, but shorter
a.tounicode()
```

But then you have a unicode string and not a `bytes()` object.

Answer (score 1):

What you did was to explicitly request a `bytes` representation of your array. Naturally this is not equal to a unicode representation.

From the docs:

> array.tostring(): Deprecated alias for tobytes().
>
> array.tobytes(): Convert the array to an array of machine values
>   and return the bytes representation (the same sequence of bytes
>   that would be written to a file by the tofile() method.)
>
> New in version 3.2: tostring() is renamed to tobytes() for clarity.

You need to use `tounicode` instead:

```
>>> import array
>>> s = "a\xbb\ucccc\U0001dddd"
>>> array.array('u', s).tounicode() == s
True
```

If you are migrating some code from Python 2.x, you will find that this is a natural equivalent of what you see there; the only difference in the Python 2.x version of the above snippet would be `s = u"etc etc"`.

Type 'u' is a dark rarely visited corner of the array module, itself a dark corner of Python. If you are NOT migrating from Python 2.x, you might like to say what you are trying to achieve (mutable strings?), and get some guidance.

Comment: Mutable Strings indeed, I am implementing a gap buffer. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps the anonymous drive-by downvoter might like to leave an explanation, or a correction?

Comment: `tostring()` is hardly "explicitly" requesting a bytes object. It does not seem entirely unreasonable to expect a method named "tostring" to return a string. IMO the decision to alias it to tobytes rather than tounicode is a violation of the principle of least surprise. But hey, I'm not the BDFL.